# How to configure a WCF client using basicHttpBinding and Username authentication over https

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I'm trying to consume a web service provided by another group within our company.  The service is written in Java and their JAVA test client functions properly.  However, I cannot get a .NET4.0 or .NET 4.5 based WCF client to talk to it.  They require https transport and since its JAVA I'm using basicHttpBinding.  They also require Username/Password.  In JAVA, they are saying the username/password is at the binding level and when looking at a message that was captured from their test code, there is NO evidence of the username or password being sent.  I can connect to their service but cannot get authenticated because they are not seeing my username & password.  Username and password is being set in code.  I am currently testing against their dev server using their self signed cert.  Our endpoints are physically 1500 miles apart but connect via internal corporate (secure) network.

I just need to know the proper config settings for "binding", "behavior", and "endpoint" to use at the client.  I can post my settings but that would just be misleading as I've tried 100's of them and none give the desired result.

Any help you can give will be useful as long as it doesn't involve any changes on (or knowledge of) the service host side (its probably not even IIS).

Thanks for your thoughts.

Java client code looks like this:

```
ServiceImplServiceLocator locator = new ServiceImplServiceLocator();
locator.setServiceEndpointAddress( "https://<hostaddr>:8443/Service" );
locator.setServiceWSDDServiceName("Service");

ServiceImpl service = locator.getService();

ServiceSoapBindingStub binding = (ServiceSoapBindingStub) service;
binding.setUsername("Username");
binding.setPassword("Password");

// call web service
Return = binding.ServiceMethod( ... );
```

Comment: If I have understood well, you have a  WCF server that is again client of a Java Service right? So you don't need WCF endpoint to connect to it. WCF endpoints are for WCF service client. Can you tell how you are connecting to the Java Service - i.e. Code snippet

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm trying to consume an existing web service.  The service was written in java.  I am NOT creating a WCF service.  I'm only trying to create a client to the java based service.  I cannot query for the WSDL - they gave me the files and I created the proxy code using svcutil.exe.  When I do that a WCF client gets created.